# SignalR makes IIS hang after rebuild

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

Windows 8.1. IIS 8.5. SignalR versions:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Whenever I rebuild my project/solution, IIS spikes to max CPU usage and I cannot reload my page. I checked procmon.exe and it reports an enormous amount (>20 000/s) of "RegOpenKey/RegQueryKey" operations like these ones:

```
Date & Time:    19.11.2014 10:47:20
Event Class:    Registry
Operation:  RegQueryKey
Result: SUCCESS
Path:   HKLM
TID:    23272
Duration:   0.0000059
Query:  HandleTags
HandleTags: 0x0

Date & Time:    19.11.2014 10:47:20
Event Class:    Registry
Operation:  RegOpenKey
Result: REPARSE
Path:   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SignalR\Performance
TID:    23272
Duration:   0.0000121
Desired Access: Read


Date & Time:    19.11.2014 10:47:20
Event Class:    Registry
Operation:  RegOpenKey
Result: NAME NOT FOUND
Path:   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SignalR\Performance
TID:    23272
Duration:   0.0000062
Desired Access: Read
```

These are the steps I use to reproduce this issue:

1. Everything works fine.
2. I write some code and compile
3. SignalR does a reconnect with WebSocket transport and gets this response in the response header: "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols"
4. I do a request and IIS Worker process hangs and never comes back OR I wait t 2-3 minutes and things are working again.

I am experiencing this in IIS Express as well. Normally I resolve this by killing the IIS Worker process and reloading. Is this a permissions issue? Currently the application pool runs under my local user, but I have tried Application Pool Identity with the same results. What should be in "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SignalR\Performance"? Currently there is no such registry key on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen this behavior before. Are the 20,000/s "RegOpenKey/RegQueryKey" operations lasting from 2-3 minutes continuously? Are all of these operations accessing the "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SignalR\Performance" path?

SignalR is designed to stop further loading of performance counters after any performance counter fails to load.

Perhaps [installing the SignalR performance counters](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#perfcounters) will resolve your issue. This will create HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SignalR\Performance.

You will have to ensure that your application pool runs under a user in the "Performance Monitor Users" group.

Comment: The requests are continuous for the time it hangs, yes. I recorded ~13 000 in 0.3 seconds - all of the same type as mentioned above. Installing the performance counter did help, so thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 2):

Good news! It seems that this issue is officially raised and there is a fix applied. Just wanted to share this if anyone has the same problem.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3414

Apparently, problem was caused by a `CultureInfo` that leaked from a different `AppDomain`. It happens in `PerformanceCounter` class constructor in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

See detailed analysis here: http://www.zpqrtbnk.net/posts/appdomains-threads-cultureinfos-and-paracetamol

At the time of writing a new package is not yet released, but soon fix should become available through official NuGet feed. Fix is contained in `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core` package.