# Visual Studio 2015: Debug session does not terminate properly

Tags: debugging, iis, signalr, visual-studio-2015

I've recently picked back up a year old MVC5/WebAPI2 (and SignalR) application which ran just fine under VS2013.

In VS2015 I however keep struggling with what appears to be hanging debug sessions: When starting a debug session VS2015 hangs on "Build succeeded" with no output in the console. The *solution* is to terminate the IIS Worker Process (which appear locked at 20-30% CPU Usage) via the Task Manager. Upon doing that VS throws a [general error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.debug.error.http);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true) and stops. When retrying once again it works normally until next stop-then-start.

It makes no difference if I stop (Shift+F5) the debug session or restart (Ctrl+Shift+F5) it, either appears to lock up the IIS process. What however does work is going to Debug -> Terminate All, then the debug session starts without hick-up.

I have tried disabling pretty much all debug tools (including Edit-and-Contiune), but nothing has worked so far. I should also mention that running the application on IIS Express does not work at all: It hangs during startup no matter what.

**Update**: Attaching the error message that pops up if I let the debug startup process time out. I have of course tried all the suggested solutions which the "help" button takes me to.

[image]

**Update II**: It looks like the problem might be related to SignalR. I've been working without problem for the last hour or so, but now stepped into the part of the application which uses SignalR. After stopping and changing some code, the debug session would not start again.

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2015/02/17/iis-visual-studio-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server/)

Comment: That link does not work, this appears to be a bug in either VS 2015 or IIS Express. I don't recall this being an issue in 2012 or 2013. But ever since MS changed from Cassini to IIS Express, I have had issues with stopping a debug at random times. Sometimes the issue does not disrupt my work but other times it will. For example, I was writing an html file to disk using the AJAX HtmlEditorExtender. After testing, stopped the web app, made some more code changes, tried to run the web page again, but the html file was still in use, locked by the previous process. ugh!! Had to kill it in TaskMgr.

Comment: FYI, I do not have SignalR in this project, but I have had some demo projects where I did use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Ensure that you turn on ‘Internet Information Services Hostable Web
>   Core’ along with all the other .NET / IIS feautes

Try to Change the IIS Settings Shown in [this](http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2015/02/17/iis-visual-studio-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server/) Article

Comment: This looks promising, but given the nature of the problem I'll hold of a while before accepting. Hope you understand.

Comment: @KGChristensen Can you consider this Solution or do you want to hold of a while?

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be working on the project where the problem resides until the end of this week. It did look like the problem reoccurred just before the weekend, but I was unable to confirm. So, please hold on a little longer.

Comment: Although I would love an explanation for why this module seemed to have done the magic trick (and apparently not needed for - any - other project I've worked on to this date), this answer solved it: The problem has not occurred since. Thanks.

Comment: @KGChristensen  I cant answer **Why** but i can tell what does **Hostable WebCore (HWC)**  Do. This feature is implemented in a DLL called `hwebcore.dll`, that exports two simple methods:1. **WebCoreActivate**  2. **WebCoreShutdown** .In this WebcoreActivate This method allows you to start the server. For More Infor Refer this [IIS 7.0 Hostable Web Core](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem isn't fixed after all. Just starting happening again with no apparent reason. So, well, damn.

Comment: DId u rechecked the IIS Settings?

Comment: and browser you are using for debugging ?

Comment: @KGChristensen **First Method**
Hit Shift+F5 when in Visual Studio and this will terminate the current debug session. You can then hit F5 and this will start a new debug session.
**Second Method**
Reset the IIS and open your application using visual studio and run it will work for you
Open Command Prompt
Start >> Run >> Type cmd and click OK
In command prompt Type iisreset and click OK

Comment: This is what Official MSDN [says](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/810974ee-64c8-42e6-a107-7f9ea467e477/the-web-server-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-manner-this-may-be-because-another-debugger-is-already?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

Comment: As mentioned in the question what you describe is what I've been doing to get it working (kill the iis process or iisreset). No changes was made to iis settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91805/discussion-between-webruster-and-kg-christensen).

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, and the solution was to install signalR performance counters.

[SignalR performance counters](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#perfcounters)

Similar question with solution: [SignalR makes IIS hang after rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019004/signalr-makes-iis-hang-after-rebuild)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this problem ended up driving me up the wall which finally lead to a refactor to remove SignalR from the application. Once SignalR was gone, so was the problem. In other words, unfortunately I cannot accept your answer as it can't be reproduced any longer.